# Additional optional moderator election question

Tags: discussion, moderation, election, moderators

Sorry, I'm late with this question, I'll explain why:

I was undecided whether I should run in this election. I had skipped the last elections, because to me it still felt too much like gunning for Monica's chair. No offense to those who did, this is a personal decision and we do need moderators, so I'm happy someone else felt more positive about it.

I finally decided to put my name up and answered the questions, when I was reminded, that I had been suspended on another site of this network over the last year and was therefore not eligible for election.

So I'm sorry I'm late with this question and it's not an official one, but it did not cross my mind until the system popped the corresponding error message into my face and maybe the candidates have an answer they would like to share.

---

**Question:**

Up until 2019, the following quote had been my mission statement. In 2020, I got banned (sorry, "suspended") for saying it out loud. Since the ban was issued by a CM and the globally valid CoC was cited as the reason/justification, I have to assume the same rules go for TWP.

So my question is, if I had posted the following not as a quote but as my actual, current opinion, would you suspend me?

> We are here to help other people with their problems, free of charge, in the language we use to communicate, to the latest standard taught in schools today so everybody out there can access our shared knowledge equally.

Comment: Please note that I do not seek to *discuss* the policy behind this, as discussing it is forbidden speech, too (you can if you want to challenge the people with ban privileges, I won't). Your answer can be as short as "Yes, I would, I stand by the CoC and this interpretation of it".

Comment: Without any supporting context, your quote above has nothing to be worried about, apart from being slightly over-wordy.  It's kind of expected that we should communicate in a clear manner so that all users, irrespective of language abilities can understand what we're talking about.

Comment: *So my question is, if I had posted the following not as a quote but as my actual, current opinion, would you suspend me?* No. But I suspect that was *not* the reason for the suspension, it was probably due to *Monica fatigue* and wanting to change the narrative.

Comment: @nvoigt You definitely should run!

Comment: @Neo system blocks this, and I complained against such blocks over 5 years ago, see [Let's disallow moderator nominations from people who've been suspended in the past year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274131/165773)

Comment: @nvoigt if this is true, the system blocks this, then you may wanna contact the CM team to see about an exception.

Comment: @Neo It does. But I'm not interested in going to the people that suspended me in the first place to beg for a favor. To me, that would only make sense if I did something wrong and regret it.

Comment: There was a lot of discussion during "the situation" that would seem to be completely innocuous, but that would be cause for concern when looked at in context. Instead of asking "Don't you think it was unfair that I was suspended for this quote?" it would be better (IMO) to ask more directly about the real issue: Where do you draw the line so that innocent people aren't caught in the crossfire when some people are abusing "presume good faith" to post inflammatory things? Handling that sort of trolling is notoriously difficult.

Comment: @ColleenV Excellent point.....btw I think you should run too...

Comment: @Neo I've done my time and I'm just an upstanding community member now :) But thank you for the vote of confidence.

Comment: What is the difference between "a quote" and "[your] actual current opinion"? If you said the words surely they should be the same (I assume the quote wasn't originally someone else's)?

Comment: If you were eligible, I'd vote for you, despite the fact that we've bumped heads MANY times in the past, I respect you.  I've been suspended numerous times myself for various reasons.  If you cannot say what you mean, you cannot mean what you say

Comment: Outside of any context, I'm willing to bet no-one will ban you for that quote, which makes the question somewhat meaningless and, if I'm being honest, it also makes me suspicious of your intentions with posting this. Even within context, I very much doubt someone would be banned for that quote alone, except in very rare circumstances where there's already been multiple requests for people to stop dragging out the discussion further. I expect the comment was more just the final straw in a range of your comments that either crosses the line by themselves or are simply intended to antagonise.

Comment: @BernhardBarker The important part here "standard English as taught in schools today". Doing that is against the current CoC. You are required to speak/write non-standard English upon request, the non-standard part being freely choosable by your communication-partner. I do not want to discuss this and I hope I found neutral words to describe it. I just want to find out if the new moderator would suspend people that decide standard English is our compromise for communication or not.

Comment: @nvoigt Again, that comment is not in any way ban-worthy outside of context (and also not even within the context of the current CoC). I very much doubt anyone would care if you, for example, post that on your user profile without doing anything else. So I don't see a reason to ask potential moderators about it. If, however, you, for example, write a series of Meta posts where you insist that the CoC is wrong or how you refuse to follow it, or you actually just repeatedly or egregiously violate the CoC, that is a very different issue from just one comment in isolation that has some subtext

Comment: ... To be clear, this quote (as far as I can tell) had nothing to do with your suspension - I can see that you may have vastly edited the quote that did lead to you being suspended to get to this version but this exact text is not what you wrote and the suspension was less related to the specific text and more to your actions in response to its removal. I'm more than happy to discuss the suspension privately if you wish.

Comment: @Catija Saying you *removed* something from my post with moderator powers, but my suspension was *not* because of what you *removed*, but because of the fact that I did not *like it being removed* is hypocritical. If what you removed was not against the CoC to begin with, you should not have removed it and everything that followed had no basis whatsoever and would be called harassment and abuse of power under normal circumstances. Or it *was* indeed wrong and against the CoC and it was all fine policing. Either I did something wrong in the part you removed, or not. Which one is it?

Comment: It doesn't take moderator powers to edit something out of a post. Anyone could have removed it - but this isn't the place to discuss that, unless you would like me to explain the entire situation publicly, here on an unrelated site. And, I'd also ask you to re-read my statement. I specifically said that the actual quote did lead to your suspension but that this watered-down version is not what you wrote.

Comment: Now you are kidding, right? "Anybody"? You aren't even responsible anymore for your own actions? You know that SE has an [edit history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/355081/5) (probably needs 10k to see, since it was deleted by mods) so we can see if it was just a random "anybody" or maybe exactly you with a diamond?

Comment: You're accusing me of abusing moderator powers to edit your post. I edited your post a single time with an ability that anyone with 2k reputation on the site could have done - that's... in no way an abuse of moderator powers. I also ceased to have any involvement in the situation after that - the suspension and all of the mod messages you were sent were not sent by me - though I understand you wouldn't have known that. Other than editing your answer, I did nothing and did not abuse any powers as a mod or staff member.

Comment: So... editing it back would have been fine, after a diamond mod edited it with the remark that it is offensive an alienating? Personally, I would have found it more obvious to be banned for editing it back *in*.

Comment: Anyway, you said your part, I said mine, the fact remains that I am not allowed to speak my mind or even use standard English because of rules you enforce. I have to obey or be banished. Not the leadership I expect from people carrying a diamond, and *exactly* what I want to know from the candidates here before I cast a vote. As I said, I am fine with not discussing it, if a potential mod writes a Yes/No answer, I'm good and have a better picture who to vote for.

Comment: And as far as "oh, I did it as a normal user" goes, maybe read question #7 of the mod questions.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, since nobody asked any questions to clarify in comments. If something is unclear... just ask?

Comment: I explained why I closed it in [my answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6879/33683) ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about re-litigating a beef from some other stack.

Comment: @mxyzplk Please note that I did not bring that "beef" up. I said very clearly I do not need to discuss this, all I want is a yes or no answer that can easily been given on the quote, regardless of source. That is my very first comment here, before non-elected moderators showed up and made it into a beef. This is not about another site, but about the moderators and the rules of this site. You may notice that not a single potential moderator came here and did that. Said, "Yes, that's against the CoC and I will be bound by it to take action on your account". Such an easy answer to give, no?

Comment: This seems to be more about the rules as written rather than how a specific mod will act. Mods are required to enforce the site policies. If something violates the site policies, it is their responsibility to do something about that (up to and including issuing a suspension). If it doesn't violate the site policies, they should not issue a suspension. Which is to say we should expect every potential and active mod to give roughly the same answer. 1/2

Comment: Mods may answer a bit differently due to differences in opinion and interpretation (and of course context), but one would expect mods to try to resolve such differences to minimise the difference between how 2 mods will handle the same situation. And of course mods are probably also given more detailed instruction about the rules and enforcement once elected, so their current thoughts on what violates the rules may not be particularly useful. Unless it's more a question of their personal feelings regardless of what they'd actually do, in which case I'd simply disapprove rather than object. 2/2

Comment: I think this question should be stated more explicitly, but I now understand why you might be reluctant to do so. I don’t think yes or no questions are particularly useful when trying to figure out where a candidate stands, although maybe it says something that only Kilisi was fearless enough to try to tackle it. :) I would vote to close this if it wasn’t election related. I think that we should be more forgiving of questions trying to understand what sort of moderator a  candidate would be as long as the question doesn’t violate the CoC. Candidates are free to ignore the question.

Comment: @ColleenV I think there should be some restrictions on what we're allowed to ask candidates. For example, asking them about their personal life, family or health or whatever (beyond indirect questions like "how much time can you spend on moderation") would be quite inappropriate in my opinion. Whether the objections raised here is sufficient reason to disallow the question is of course up for debate. Closing or deleting a disallowed question seems appropriate. That said, such closure can be a constructive sign about what's (not) allowed.

Comment: @BernhardBarker If it doesn't violate the CoC the asking of it shouldn't be shut down. Inappropriate is different from offensive. Candidates aren't required to answer any particular question, and they can always ignore it. An answer of "I'm not comfortable answering that question because it's too personal." would be a fine answer in my opinion. Moderators are going to have to handle tough situations and interact with people who are emotional about a situation, and I think protecting candidates from questions is counterproductive.

Comment: @ColleenV I see closing this less as "protecting candidates" (even if that's a side effect) and more as focusing the narrative on what's actually relevant and appropriate, in the same way we would close random questions about programming on the main Workplace site, close random questions about space on Workplace Meta and delete pretty much anything anywhere asking anyone for personal details (or providing said details) outside the scope of what's necessary to answer a question.

Comment: @BernhardBarker Respectfully, who are you to decide what is appropriate and relevant information for someone else to have in order to make their decision on how to cast their vote? Election questions aren't at all similar to questions asked on a main site. I have been a moderator, and this question isn't even close to the trickiest situation I had to deal with. It is very difficult to get a sense of how someone will make the judgement calls being a mod requires. Allowing some portion of the community to suppress a question that a candidate is free to ignore is not constructive.

Comment: @ColleenV This isn't a public forum (in the legal sense) where anyone can freely say or ask (pretty much) whatever they want. If we want to restrict what people can ask potential moderators, that's well within our rights, just like it's well within our rights to restrict content elsewhere on the site. Who am I? I'm someone allowed to discuss what's appropriate on this site as well as judge it to a reasonable degree with up-, down-, close- and delete votes, just like you. Although it says something that a community manager closed this question.

Comment: @BernhardBarker Just because you have the *right* to do something, doesn't mean it should be done. I disagree with your judgement of what is inappropriate. CMs are human and make mistakes, especially when someone is (unfairly IMO) questioning their fairness. "I don't like this question" is not a valid close reason. Suppressing questions during an election should be done with more care, and with sounder reasoning. What harm is done by allowing someone to ask candidates to **voluntarily** answer a question? I see a lot of harm in allowing a group to suppress a POV during an election.

Comment: @ColleenV The reasons mentioned are a lot more complex than simply not liking the question and are probably closer to "This doesn't appear to have much to do with a moderator's ability to moderate" (which seems like a pretty reasonable objection to a question directed at potential moderators). On the surface it might seem to be about a moderator's ability to moderate, but the comments explain why it doesn't seem to really be about that. Allowing inappropriate questions opens the door to more inappropriate questions. I'm sure even public office election debates would block certain questions.

Comment: @BernhardBarker "It seems like it has nothing to do with a moderator's ability to moderate." in *your opinion*. There's no reason that candidates should be prevented from answering a question someone has asked because you don't think it's a good question. If a candidate doesn't think it's relevant or doesn't understand it, they don't have to answer it. "Slippery slope" is a logical fallacy. This question has been around for almost a week now, and I don't see a flood of inappropriate questions being asked of our candidates.

Comment: @ColleenV "in your opinion" - yes, exactly, and there aren't really compelling counter-arguments here to change my mind. "you don't think it's a good question" - did I ever say "good"? I primarily referred to appropriateness and relevance, which aren't the same thing. But if you think it would be totally fine to ask candidates how many kids they have, to describe their own mental disorders (if any) or what they think of the Perseverance rover, then I suppose I can only agree to disagree (even if those questions are "voluntary").

Comment: @BernhardBarker I think it's fine to ask almost any question of a person who is asking for my vote, so long as it does not violate the Code of Conduct. They can choose not to answer it, but I should be allowed to ask. I asked Snow a fairly personal question, and it turned out they were happy to answer it and I got information that helped my make my decision. If you had your way, I might not have been allowed to ask the question. Can't you see the problem with that? Whose cultural norms get applied to determine what is "appropriate"?

Comment: @ColleenV No rule is perfect, neither is not having a rule.

Comment: This reminds me why I won't run.  The CoC is not reasonable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Location specific. In general that statement sounds reasonable and I could in no way see it as worthy of disciplinary action. But by the standards of my local schools, no one would understand the statement probably including the English teacher.

Answer (score 9):

As I read through your post and the comments below it I find myself struggling to assume good faith, but I'm still gonna try to below, and I'll assume you're not *deliberately* trying to be provocative — especially because if this is just a misunderstanding, we can easily clear it up, learn something from it, and move on ^_^

If you hadn't preambled your actual question with all the context you preambled it with, anyone reading this question would've taken your quote at face value and probably wondered why such an innocuous statement would ever be deemed as problematic — taken at face value and in isolation the quote doesn't seem problematic, indeed.

However, you did add the preamble. Seeing the statement under the light of the suspension you spent the first half of your post exposing *your perspective* of, as well as the first paragraph of "the question" section is important, though.

And with that in mind, it *seems* that you're asking prospective moderators whether or not they'll abide by and enforce [the Code of Conduct](/conduct) and [all other officially announced moderator and user policies](/help/mod-agreement-policies) they'd be required to, as per [the Moderator Agreement](/legal/moderator-agreement) they'd have to sign to get access to moderator tools. To be more specific, it *seems* that you're asking whether they'd skirt [our policy surrounding personal pronouns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/208518) if it came down to it.

But, going back to the beginning of this post: I'm going to go against my gut feeling and assume that that was not your intention — that would hardly be a constructive question to ask the nominees. If that's not the case, though, I'm left scratching my head at the intention behind the question anyway. So maybe you can clarify what your intentions here were.

In the meantime, I'll close this question as unclear until you clarify how this question brings anything constructive to the table.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you *answered* the question at the same time as using your moderator powers to *close* it?

Comment: Er, you kinda made his point

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter It's not deleted. Any of the candidates could address this question in their questionnaires if they wanted to. As the question stands, it doesn't ask a question about how someone would moderate TWP. It asks candidates to second guess a CM's decision with a fraction of the context necessary to do that in a reasoned way. Not everyone standing as a candidate was eye-balls deep in the events surrounding the decision that prevents nvoigt from running.

Comment: Indeed the said "quote" by the OP mislead me too, I had completely forgotten the original post (now deleted). The current post is candy coating what was actually *meant*.

Comment: @ColleenV I would assume answering elsewhere could (quite frankly *should*) be seen as circumventing a moderator decision.

Comment: what you wrote looks merely like your opinion. And closing this question looks like abusing your power to suppress dissenting opinion. What makes it look even worse is that power you used to suppress this meta discussion comes solely from your position in the company and not from your contributions to this site. Please don't do that

Comment: @nvoigt I don’t think a candidate reading between the lines of your question and addressing your concerns in a constructive way would be a problem if they didn’t try to take a position on your suspension. I understand the reasoning behind closing it, but I think it was a bad idea. The post wasn’t generating a lot of controversy until the CM team stepped in and made it about correctly characterizing the previous situation instead of the question being asked. Sometimes it’s better to just ignore a potential provocation and see if the situation escalates on its own rather than forcing it to.

Comment: @ColleenV I think we could all stand to focus more on the lines than what is in between them.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter As the question is currently written, it's pointless if taken literally. "No I wouldn't suspend you for that quote if I saw it in your profile in the current environment." says nothing about how a candidate would moderate the actual issue unless the candidate makes it clear they understand the missing context. I understand why people are being cagey about bringing that up again, because it is very difficult to discuss that aspect of the CoC without getting the hammer dropped on you.

Comment: So, here we are wink-wink-nudge-nudging our way through what should be a straight-forward conversation about where a candidate stands when moderating an issue that is very dependent on their judgment, and has significant impact on how comfortable users feel participating on the site.

Comment: @ColleenV Remember what I said about those lines?

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter No, I'm not playing this game. Say what you mean or don't. I have no idea what you are trying to communicate. It took me years of work to get to the point where I could discuss things steeped in soft language and euphemisms without making anyone cry or having them accuse me of being a terrible person. If you can't say something in a way that I can interpret it literally and understand it, you should assume that I don't understand you.

Comment: @ColleenV I don't play games, and I don't read in between any lines.  I take things and people at face value.  It eliminates 99% of the stress.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter It also means that you miss half of what they're trying to tell you in my experience. Sorry if it seems like my frustration is directed at you, it's not. We should be able to discover if a candidate is going to tolerate people passively-aggressively refusing to comply with the CoC or if they are going to be on a search-and-destroy mission for any hint that someone might not be a "true believer". I'm confident none of our candidates fall into either of those camps, but I'm annoyed that we're not allowed to ask without risking punitive action.

Comment: @ColleenV that's why I was such a fan of the "assume good intentions" rule.  I'm also an old fart who no longer cares about the games people play.  As for my own aggression, it's never passive, I prefer to be highly active in it.  That's also one thing I really don't like about the new CoC.  It expects people to be mind readers.  If, as I suspect, you are like me, you've spent much of your life having your intentions misinterpreted and not reading the intent of others well either.  That's why I made the "reading the lines" comment.  There is too much of projecting intent that does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

*Disclaimer: I have been asked what my current position on this is since I am running for moderator. None of this answer is supposed to disrespect or hurt anybody, if you think it is, despite my intentions, please let me know in detail, I will try my best to improve it.*

## Context

At one of the other sites of the SE network, which is based on rules-based games, we have the distinction between [rai](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rai) (rules-as-*intended*) and [raw](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raw) (rules-as-*written*). One focuses on what a specifc rule is supposed to achieve in the game, the other more on what can be done to abide by the letter of the rule, and more often than not, how can one get the most advantage out of the actual wording, like a good lawyer in court.

## Intention

I respect and support the *intention* of the CoC. Using *any* language to intentionally hurt people (and that without doubt includes intentionally misgendering them by using anything else than their stated pronoun) is against our rules and should not be given a platform here.

## Written

I do have a bit of a problem with what is actually written. There are edge cases in those rules that I cannot resolve. And I think that is a general problem, not a *me* problem.

One edge case is inclusivity vs inclusivity. To abide by these rules, one needs a minimum level of fluency in the English language *and* a minimum level of fluency in the specific (US heavy) English culture of our time. As an example of what I mean, [someone used "sie" as a neo-pronoun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377066/is-it-acceptable-to-replace-neopronouns-used-for-made-up-characters-with-neutral/377080#377080). That is explicitely English... as evidenced by the fact that "sie" is an *actual regular pronoun* in my language, and translated means "she". The opposite of what was intended. Welcome to total confusion. So there is no global culture around this, that people already know and share. As written, (US) English culture now is just as much a barrier to entry as is English as a language. Given that my proposal to check whether questions on SE have at least one question mark in them to improve question quality was met by "how dare you expect *that* level of English proficiency, we need to be more inclusive than that!", I am dumbfounded by how I would get these two together. Am I on the side of being inclusive and supporting to the US LGBTQ+ culture at the expense of others? Or am I supportive of those other cultures and languages that simply do not have that level of cultural fluency at the expense of the LGBTQ+ community? I would love to find a compromise. I would love to simply *educate* people about this part of US culture, that would be a good compromise from my point. But since education of any sort rarely goes without a discussion, even that is against the rules as written.

Another edge case is the point of having to accept *any* word as a pronoun. If someone tells me their stated pronoun is "Xamufl/Xam", and I cannot find this in a dictionary, or at least educate myself when I google it, then I have no idea if that person is genuinely feeling so outside of the norm that they need their own unique pronoun... or if they are just a jerk that attack helicopter'd me to yank my chain.

And a third egde case... as always... is religion. How inclusive are we, if we deny religious people their views? Well, to be honest that is the least of my worries, because I am not religious enough to think that religion is a shield to hide disrespect behind. If you disrespect people, religion is no excuse for that. But I can see that I infringe on their views, even with *that* stance. And my view, that respect beats religion, might not be universal.

## Reality

And the reality is, I have not witnessed *a single incident* about pronoun misuse, or even just *explicit use* in the last three years. *Not one*. Makes me wonder why SE had to come down so hard on this. It must be a *huuge* problem on the sites I do not visit, to warrant that kind of action. And I cannot honestly say I know how I would react to problems I have not seen and will probably not see in being a moderator at Workplace.SE. Whether my "I will judge intention, not lawyer rules" approach would work there. I would have to cross that bridge when I come to it.

A lot of the controversy comes down to messaging. It is a enormous difference between educating people and scolding people. A few weeks or months before SE came down on this, there was a US late night show (I think it was Ellen on Colbert, but my memory is hazy) and they explained their stated pronoun of "they" as this: "Have we ever been intimate? No? Well, then don't act as if you know what's going on in my pants. What would my pronoun be if you stopped assuming you knew what's going on in my pants? See, that was easy." That was funny. That was witty. That was educational. That was 3 minutes late night talk and still light years better messaging of the same thing than SE's knee jerk actions and PR disaster.

## Conclusion

As a moderator, I would go with the (at least *my perceived*) intention of the rules. I will not accept intentional harassment, under whatever motivation or in whatever disguise.

Personally, I consider myself educated enough as far as that cultural topic goes and willing to learn should that prove insufficient.

This site is about international community and education and learning. My main focus is still on getting people the answers to their questions. The solution is education, not banning clueless people and telling them to go get educated elsewhere. Banning someone for not being educated enough is contrary to anything I believe this site stands for.

I will not undo their actions, should other moderators feel the need to interpret the rules more strictly or judge people's intentions differently. But I will not throw the first stone on people I consider breaking those rules unintentionally.

---

I assume, that this is acceptable and that my criticism falls under

> [SE will] Respect your right to speak openly to question and challenge policy without reprisal so long as such speech does not break the Code of Conduct.

However, it is obviously open to the individual voter to decide whether they like that opinion in their moderator, or not.

Comment: Do you support someones right to use the word "they" as a gender-neutral singular pronoun, even if they are told "Don't use they. My pronoun is 'he' "?

Comment: If someone explicitely requests a specific pronoun (in that case "he") *for himself* then that person should be addressed as "he". Calling that person "they" would be misgendering, in that specific case, after that person explicitely requested said pronoun, even intentionally. I do not support pointlessly changing pronouns after the fact. If you write a two page answer labelling the unknown "user12345" "the OP, they" I don't see a need to change that if that user comes out *after* and sets their gender. It wasn't known at the time of writing. It is known *now*, so from now on, it's "he".

Comment: Cool. So your belief is that gender neutral they isn't actually gender neutral at all.

Comment: My believe is that gender neutral *is* gender neutral. And that addressing someone who expressedly told you their gender intentionally in a gender neutral way is insulting. At least where I come from, that is a kindergarden level insult for kids and a sexual slur for teenagers (and people of all ages that behave like teenagers). However, I am not a native speaker, if you can hook me up with more information about it, and how addressing people as "they" even though you know their gender is fine, I might learn something new about the English language. Would certainly not be the first time.

Comment: Gender neutral just means nothing is being said about their gender. It doesn't mean they are neither male nor female. It means that information is not attempting to be conveyed. The word "they" is suitable for all genders.

Comment: Other gender-neutral pronouns, (that for some reason, don't seem to cause problems): you, many, those, who, both, one etc. Some people use gender neutral words by default where the gender is not important. Misgendering is the offensive thing here, but if nothing is being said of the gender at all, I don't understand how that can occur.

Comment: Well, let's cut it short: discussing this part of the policy is also against policy. And while I absolutely disagree with any policy censoring content or discussion based on content, I have followod it and will continue to do so. Including enforcing it if that becomes my job. By the policies we have, if someone tells you their preferred pronoun you have to use it. And I stand by that policy. "He" clearly is a pronoun, not a troll and is very basic English that anybody can understand. Using it is the polite way, not using it on purpose is rude.

Comment: I'm not commenting on policy at all. Sorry I disagree with what you say. I try not to use gendered pronouns at all, regardless of how "obvious" it is. It's illogical. By definition, if I say: "I respect everybody on Stack Exchange" I'm actually not following the policy apparently, because 'everybody' is a pronoun, and I am sure there is at least one person on Stack Exchange that has a "preferred pronoun" which is not "everybody". Note that the expression "preferred pronoun" is offensive because it suggests gender identity is merely a preference.

Comment: The COC is pretty clear on that: "No bigotry. [...] Use stated pronouns (when known)." If you see that as a problem or illogical, it is up to you to discuss that with our corporate overlord who gave us these rules. The answer to the question of whether I would abide by these rules and enforce them if I am elected to do so, is a **yes**.

Comment: Good to know. Don't expect my vote.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have never understood that "use stated pronouns" should be read as "use stated pronouns *including newopronouns* and if you default to _they_ instead of a neopronoun you are breaking the CoC". My understanding was that the "use stated pronouns" was referring mostly to the standard he/she and we are always allowed to use _they_ instead.

Comment: You can find more detail here: [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364). Basically, if someone insists that you absolutely must use a neopronoun for them, that is the only time you will be expected to and everyone will understand if you get it wrong a few times. So we're talking about maybe once every 5 years in a chat room or something, this really isn't a common occurrence at all. for the vast, vast majority of cases, using singular _they_ is fine. For what it's worth, I have yet to come across a single case of a neopronoun in the SE wild.

Comment: @terdon Appreciate the input. I think I'm on the same page and most of the usual discussions on this topic tend to be restricted to the field of thought experiments, though of course this site in particular has a notable history in this area that tends to inflame reactions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your stance @nvoigt! I do think it's useful to get a bit of insight into your position, though that comment you left here really would have been enough for me. ;)

Comment: I have only one friend who explicity uses neopronouns @terdon, but Zie is not on stack exchange. Most of my non-binary friends prefer singular they/them as the most important thing to them appears to be not being casually assigned a gender they don't identify with, and the gender neutral term we've had since the 13th century is more than adequate to do that. For someone to assert that using `they` to refer to someone is equivalent to assigning someone with a gender of non-binary is a big red gender-essentialism flag to me.